# Google _gaq.push not in anatlycis

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, statistics

I want custom tracking in analytics. I have a custom JavaScript site.

When you click on the button I fire this code:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',1, 'Stappen', 'Eerste stap - Type woning']);
```

But when I go to analytics, by the events, it's not showing. It's not showing in analytics. What have I done wrong, am I missing something?

The code in the header:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34399608-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ga.js version on the analytics script? This is a requirement to use event tracking.

I would also look at the even tracking code, the 1 would need to be '1', and look like the code below on your html button:

```
<button type="button" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '1', 'Stappen', 'Eerste stap - Type woning']);">Button</button>
```

Google event tracking help section is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide